# ngDocs example using ngAnimate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

I am generating my API documentation using [grunt-ngDocs](https://github.com/m7r/grunt-ngdocs). I am having trouble using examples that contain animation using ngAnimate. I have included angular-animate script within the scripts option (as required by ngdocs) and I see animations occurring when I navigate through the generated documentation.

Here is my example code

```
/** 
 * @ngdoc directive
 * (other of ng-doc options)
 *
 * @example
 <example module="exampleAnimationModule"> 
   <file name="index.html">
     <div class="box" my-animation>Click Me</div>
   </file> 

   <file name="styles.css">
     .box {
       border: 1px solid black;
       height: 100px;
       width: 100px;
      }
     .box.red {
       background-color: red;
     }
   </file>

   <file name="script.js">
     angular.module('exampleAnimationModule', ['ngAnimate'])
     .directive('myAnimation', function($animate){
       return {
         link: function(scope, element, attrs, fn) {
           element.on('click', function(){
             scope.$apply(function(){
               $animate.addClass(element, 'red');
             });
          });
         }
       };
     });
   </file>     
 </example>
 */
```

When I view the documentation, the demo renders correctly but when I click on the box nothing happens. However, when I click on something else in the documentation that starts a $digest cycle, the animation occurs.

It is almost as though the `scope.$apply()` isn't working properly. It is more interesting that when I click on the 'View in Plnkr' link, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally found the answer in ngdocs source code. There is an optional animations attribute on the `<example>` tag that can be set to true. When it is on, it renders a 'Animations On/Off' button on the screen that works properly.

```
<example module="exampleAnimationModule" animations="true">
```

I cannot find this option anywhere in the documentation. I found it within [this regex](https://github.com/m7r/grunt-ngdocs/blob/347b5526f662cc40ea68f4a62f2b8efb6d7a78cf/src/ngdoc.js#L204)

Comment: Similar situations here, I have animations on an ng-repeat and they don't work in docs also after adding `animations="true"` to the sample. Any idea?

Comment: Could you post an example of the comment usage and version of ngDocs?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue generating documentation with animation for `ng-repeat` directive.

Here is the `ng-doc` example code:

```
<example module="sampleTable2" animations="true">
<file name="index.html">
  <div ng-controller="SampleCtrl2 as vm">
    <xos-table data="vm.data" config="vm.config"></xos-table>
  </div>
</file>
<file name="script.js">
  angular.module('sampleTable2', ['xos.uiComponents', 'ngAnimate'])
  .controller('SampleCtrl2', function(){
    this.config = {
      columns: [
        {
          label: 'First Name', // column title
          prop: 'name' // property to read in the data array
        },
        {
          label: 'Last Name',
          prop: 'lastname'
        }
      ],
      classes: 'table table-striped table-condensed', // table classes, default to `table table-striped table-bordered`
      actions: [ // if defined add an action column
        {
          label: 'delete', // label
          icon: 'remove', // icons, refers to bootstraps glyphicon
          cb: (user) => { // callback, get feeded with the full object
            console.log(user);
          },
          color: 'red' // icon color
        }
      ],
      filter: 'field', // can be by `field` or `fulltext`
      order: true
    };

    this.data = [
      {
        name: 'John',
        lastname: 'Doe'
      },
      {
        name: 'Gili',
        lastname: 'Fereydoun'
      }
    ]
  });
</file>
```

The full code is here: https://github.com/open-cloud/xos/tree/feature/common-components/views/ngXosLib/xosHelpers/src/ui_components/dumbComponents/table

While to generate the documentation I'm using `gulp ng-docs v0.2.13`